# Spring boot, thymeleaf @PostMapping 405 error message

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am new here and also new in java programing. I've been strugling second day now with @PostMapping in spring boot MVC. I can;t understand what's wrong with my code. I'm working on very simple bank account project.

I can't find out whats wrong with connecting @PostMapping in AccountController in execute deposit method, and with thymeleaf form, which should add amount of deposit to account ballance. I'm just started learning spring so please be gentle:)

```
`@Controller
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;
    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    // display all accounts
    @AliasFor(value = "accounts")
    @GetMapping("/accounts")
    public String showAccountsList(Model model) {
        List<Account> listAccounts = accountService.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("listAccounts", listAccounts);
        return "accounts";
    }

    @Autowired
    public AccountController(AccountService accountService) {
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }

    //get Account by Id
    @GetMapping("accounts/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Account> getAccountById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Account account = accountRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Account with id: " + id + " does not exist"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(account);
    }

    @GetMapping("/account_operations/{id}")
    public String getAccountDetailsById(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        Account account = accountRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Account with id: " + id + " does not exist"));

        model.addAttribute("account", account);
        return "account_operations";
    }

    @GetMapping("/account_operations/deposit/{id}")
    public String makeDeposit(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        Account account = accountRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Account with id: " + id + " does not exist"));

        model.addAttribute("account", account);
        return "deposit";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/account_operations/deposit/{id}")
    public String executeDeposit(@ModelAttribute("amount") double amount, Account account, RedirectAttributes ra) {

        accountService.executeDeposit(account, amount);
        ra.addFlashAttribute("message", "The customer has been saved successfully.");
        return "redirect:/customer_accounts";
    }`

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Deposit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">

    <div><h2>Deposit</h2></div>
    <div class="m-3">
        <a class="h4" th:href="@{/accounts}">Back to accounts</a>
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div th:if="${account}">
            <h2>Deposit to account:</h2>
            <h3>[[${account.accountNumber}]]</h3>
            <p>[[${account.balance}]]</p>
            <p>[[${account.accountType}]]</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Amount to deposit</h2>
            <form th:action="@{/account_operations/deposit}" method="post" th:object="${account}" style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; font-size: small">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="amount" class="form-label">Amount</label>
                    <input type="number" th:value="${amount}" th:field="*{amount}" name="amount" id="amount" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Deposit Amount" required>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-2">Deposit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-2" onclick="cancelForm()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>`



`@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@SecondaryTable(name = "customer", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = ""))
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private double balance;
    private double interest;
    private String accountNumber;
    private AccountType accountType;
    private double amount;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference

    private Customer customer;

    public Account(double balance, double interest, AccountType accountType) {
        this.balance = balance;
        this.interest = interest;
        this.accountNumber = generateIbanAccountNumber();
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }

    public String generateIbanAccountNumber() {
        return new Iban.Builder().countryCode(CountryCode.PL).bankCode("696").buildRandom().toString();
    }

    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        balance -= amount;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }
}`
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you do also have a mapping for "/customer_accounts" somewhere?

Comment: @Andrzej Płeczkan, you're missing ModelAttribute("account") in your endpoint method signature.

Answer (score 0):

You should have csrf token in your form. Put below code before form closing tag.

```
<input 
  type="hidden" 
  th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" 
  th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't fix issue with error that I am having:

Comment: There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported